# splitting data under specific value after the sum of it

Tags: awk

How do I split the `input.txt` after the sum of size `column 1` under `80000`

input.txt

```
11736 textDYN.txt
65736 textMV.txt
61812 textDYN_1.txt
11750 textGB.txt
```

---

`$1 < 80000`

`total sum = 77472 under 80000` then, it will be output as `output_001.txt`

```
11736 textDYN.txt
65736 textMV.txt
```

`total sum = 73562 under 80000` then, it will be output as `output_002.txt`

```
61812 textDYN_1.txt
11750 textGB.txt
```

Comment: What should happen in case sum is more than 80000? And is it always 2 lines sum you need to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    sub(/\r$/,"")
    sum += $1
}
(NR == 1) || (sum > 80000) {
    close(out)
    out = sprintf("output_%03d.txt",++cnt)
    sum = $1
}
{ print $0 " > " out }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
11736 textDYN.txt > output_001.txt
65736 textMV.txt > output_001.txt
61812 textDYN_1.txt > output_002.txt
11750 textGB.txt > output_002.txt
```

Change `print $0 " > " out` to `print > out` when done testing.

Comment: Very nice. So you are throwing in what looks like a pre-OSX fix with `sub(/\r$/,"")`?   How is it you knew to do that here as opposed to elsewhere?

Comment: I copy/pasted the sample input from the question and it had `\r\n` at the end of each line instead of just `\n`. It's handling common and garden DOS line endings,.

Comment: Whew, you had me scratching my head. Why not `sub(/\r\n*$/,"")` as the `\r$` would be mac pre-OSX wouldn't it?

Comment: The `\n` has already been consumed by the time your awk script sees it - `\n` is the RS that awk used to split the file into records.

Comment: That's the answer. I was thinking too literally about line endings.

Comment: how do I change the initial number ie.  `output_004.txt` , if I want the output starting from 4, I've changed it `cnt = 4`, but it stuck till `output_5.txt`, should I edit this question?

Comment: `awk -v cnt=3 -f tst.awk file` or add `BEGIN{cnt=3}` at the top.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand how you want to split your files, you would need to handle the case where the sum of `$1` is less than `80000` (by adding to `sum`), the case where it is more than `80000` (updating to output to a new filename and resetting the sum) and a third rule that writes to the current filename.

You could do something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN {sum=0; cnt=1; fn=sprintf("output_%03d.txt", cnt++)} 
    sum < 80000 {sum+=$1}
    sum >= 80000 {fn=sprintf("output_%03d.txt", cnt++); sum=0}
    {print $0 > fn}
' file
```

An example using your input data in `file` would be:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {sum=0; cnt=1; fn=sprintf("output_%03d.txt", cnt++)}
>     sum < 80000 {sum+=$1}
>     sum >= 80000 {fn=sprintf("output_%03d.txt", cnt++); sum=0}
>     {print $0 > fn}
> ' file
```

**Resulting Files**

```
$ cat output_001.txt
11736 textDYN.txt
65736 textMV.txt

$ cat output_002.txt
61812 textDYN_1.txt
11750 textGB.txt
```

If that isn't what you were attempting, please let me know and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: Thank you. There is usually more than one way to skin-the-cat with `awk`. However, when the other answer is from @EdMorton... his will generally be the more refined of the two `:)`